# cx_oracle on Python 3.5 in a RedHat based environment?

Tags: python, linux, oracle, cx-oracle

On the cx_oracle download page on Python package index, I see both Windows and Linux version of cx_oracle. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle

However, I only see Python 3.5 versions for Windows.

Is it possible to use Python 3.5 on a RedHat based Linux Distribution with cx_oracle? If so, how? If not, what other available libraries can use Python 3.5 and Oracle 11.2 on RedHat based Linux distributions?

Comment: can't you just try `pip install cx_Oracle`?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to build it from source. I use it with Oracle Enterprise Linux 7.3 which is a variant of RedHat. But I use it with Python 2.7.  Still, I built cx_Oracle from source and that worked for me. Why not try it with Python 3.5?

Note that you need an Oracle client installed before you install cx_Oracle.

Bobby

Comment: I'll give this a try and report back.